# Regarding client secret in OAUTH token authentication

Tags: oauth2-playground

I need to implement an API for getting the refresh token every time the access token expires. For that, I need the client secret as one of the parameters but it's not being shown in the Response/Request console and instead, it's being shown as ***********.
How can u get access to the client secret so that I can call the endpoint in postman and provide the client secret as a parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create your own Application credentials (Client ID + Client Secret) on the Google Cloud console. The application credentials used in the OAuth 2 Playground are for demonstration purposes and so we hide the secret to avoid people using them by mistake.

Note: You can still configure the OAuth 2 Playground with your own credentials if you'd like to try things out, for this open the Configuration panel

Comment: I have created my own application credentials and entered them in the OAUTH configuration panel but it still shows unauthorized client.